# How to delete .php extension from URL?

Tags: mod-rewrite

How can I delete the .php extension from URL with mod_rewrite?

For example:

```
test.com/index.php -> test.com/index/
test.com/contact.php -> test.com/contact/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php
```

If the user typed in `http://example.com/index/` they would get the actual page of `http://example.com/index.php`

Basically this rule says "match everything from the base url up to a slash, or the end if no slash, but not including the slash. Then give the user that matched part with .php appended to the end."

This is only going to work for the first level of directory; ie. this will not match on `example.com/index/some/other/stuff` - no redirect there.

Comment: i want to first level only. but your code get error "500 Internal Server Error".

Comment: `index.php` is also matched by `^([^/]+)/?$`.

Comment: A little tweak: `RewriteRule ^([^\/\.]+)/?$ $1.php [L,NS]`. It should work now ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to redirect requests to `/index.php` to `/index/`, try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ (/[^?\ ]+)\.php[?\ ]
RewriteRule .+\.php$ %1/ [L,R=301]
```

And for the other direction:

```
RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1.php [L]
```

You can also use both rules at the same time to get this behavior:

- requests of `/index.php` are getting redirected externally to `/index/`
- requests of `/index/` are getting rewritten internally to `/index.php`

Comment: tanks gumbo. i want show index.php but in url show index/. ok?

Comment: @chalist: So you requested `/index.php` or `/index/` and it didn’t work?